# Multiple jQuery DatePickers with staggered date selection

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have several or a unknown amount of jQuery Date selectors on a view. Each date picker appears in a set order. I'd like to ensure that the user can only select a date which is 24 hours after the previous selection. So if there are 4 date pickers, the first one would be limited to selection from today onwards, the second from this time tomorrow onwards, the third this time on Wednesday and the fourth this time on Thursday.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

I've using a class to call the jQuery for each date picker as I don't necessarily know the amount or id's of the date pickers that will be on the page.

```
$(".publication_date").livequery(function() {
                $(this).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd M yy",
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    altField: $(this).next(),
                    minDate: new Date(),
                    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the onSelect call back on each datepicker to use set the minDate on the next datepicker?

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2010, 1 - 1, 1)
```

Comment: That is a good point (Added code above) but how do I know the next date picker to alter the date selections for?

Comment: i guess you could use a naming constraint - if the id of this datepicker is date3 then the next will be date4?

Comment: Hmm it looks to be quite a complicated task this as making a selection will need to result in all dates being checked and having their day offset changed.

Comment: Yeah, that makes it tricky alright. Just have to write a function to loop through the subsequent date pickers and if the date is invalid, then all following pickers will have to be reset. Not the friendliest for the user, but there you go. Another option would be to disable all date pickers after the current one and dont allow submission of the form until all are entered correctly.